# Output formatting with CSV and PowerSHell

Tags: csv, powershell

CSV formatted like this:

```
Username,Password
jsmith,Password!
jdoe,Password!
bob,Password!
```

PowerShell Script:

```
$users = Import-CSV -Path "C:\path\users.csv"

foreach ($user in $users) {
     Write-Host "Username: $user.Username"
     Write-Host "Password: $user.Password"
}
```

Output:

```
Username: @{Username=jsmith; Password=Password!}.Username
Password: @{Username=jsmith; Password=Password!}.Password
Username: @{Username=jdoe; Password=Password!}.Username
Password: @{Username=jdoe; Password=Password!}.Password
Username: @{Username=bob; Password=Password!}.Username
Password: @{Username=jsmith; Password=Password!}.Password
```

This is part of a larger script and I need to be able to reference using `$user.XXXX` format. Articles I've read show this should work but I'm clearly missing something silly with the formatting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to "escape" the object property into a variable when trying to interpolate it. The below would work instead:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
     Write-Host "Username: $($user.Username)"
     Write-Host "Password: $($user.Password)"
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the format string operator:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
     "Username: {0}" -f $user.Username
     "Password: {0}" -f $user.Password
}
```

Comment: Or simply `Write-Host "Username:" $user.Username` and `Write-Host "Password:" $user.Password` since `write-host` tries to convert everything to a string, and then just joins all the strings.